# Find the location driver chromium browser is installed in Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, drivers, python, selenium

I am using windows 10. In Google Colab, I executed the following commands:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt-get install -y chromium-browser
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Now I need to execute:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Could you let me know how I can search for the "path" where the driver is installed on my windows? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Didn't you install the WebDriver? It will be where you installed it to.

Comment: Yes but while installing it did not ask me for any paths... that is why I do not know.

Comment: What guide are you following to do this (Basically, where did you get the `!apt install chromium-chromedriver` command from)? Doesn't that tell you further steps for it?

Comment: Not really, I assume they are using linux: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOJiWrjFVKY&ab_channel=PythonWebScraping

Comment: I'm not closely familiar with Google Colab. But `!apt install chromium-chromedriver` is a Linux command to install a Linux package, so if that works, the other Linux commands/locations should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default install location would be `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver`.

(But all the guides I've seen on using the WebDriver in Google Colab seem to instruct to run `!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin` after the `!apt install chromium-chromedriver`.)